# Yosemite causing problems with Keychain

Tags: mac, macos, keychain

I recently updated to Yosemite. Now when I log out and then log back into my computer, I have to enter my credentials for all my applications. At the same time, dozens of windows pop up from applications that are not even open, asking for me to enter the keychain password.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running a keychain repair for both the Login and System keychains with the Keychain Access app? Applications->Utilities->Keychain Access

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different options to try to fix recurrent Keychain Access issues.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6724601